# What is `Roland's pitch` and `Yamaha's pitch`? and How to convert notes to them?

Tags: midi, pitch

[image: A sheet.]

I have an assign that convert this sheet to 'Roland's pitch' and 'Yamaha's pitch'. I have no idea about what is Roland's pitch and Yamaha's pitch, neither how to do it.
Please let me know.

[image: addtion image]

using this image.

Comment: Is the premise perhaps that Roland and Yamaha keyboards (or specific models thereof) don't play the same note for (say) MIDI note number 60? (I'm not sure if that's true - just a guess)

Comment: As far as I know, there are no such terms. Roland and Yamaha both produce keyboards, and both are re-tuneable. It may have something to do with the MIDI numbering system where one uses 0 and the other 1 as a start point. But as far as 12TET is concerned, the two should be equal in pitch.

Comment: @Tim but is there actually a standard as to which note sounds when the keyboard receives a MIDI note number? e.g. nn# 60 will usually sound a C, but is it always C4 on every keyboard?

Comment: According to [MIDI forum post](https://www.midi.org/forum/830-midi-octave-and-note-numbering-standard): > The short answer is that MIDI notes are simply a note index and do not really define the pitch of a note. The MIDI specification only defines Middle C as note number 60. So *pitch* and *MIDI* are not really connected, so your question requires substantial additional information, such that the problem becomes clear.

Comment: If it is an "assign" (assignment), why not contact the teacher or someone else on the course for clarification?

Comment: @topomorto - don't know enough, hence comment not answer.

Comment: Right now, the question as written isn't clear. It *may* have lost something in translation, or it may just be a badly worded question.

Comment: @Tim it may be clear to someone with more knowledge than us about the MIDI implementation of Roland and Yamaha keyboards though ...

Comment: @replete Thanks to your comment, but teacher says don't ask until this assign finish, and other students also have no idea about this.
So, I asked this question at here.

Comment: @Tim Maybe it's translation is not good. I am not major in music, so I can not understand all the origin things.

Comment: Your teacher must be asked. If he gives a question that no-one understands, it's not productive to anybody.

Comment: Hello folks. Middle C on a MIDI keyboard always triggers MIDI note 60, unless some kind of octave shift or transposition button has been pressed, or some alternative key assignment is being used. MIDI note 60 is assigned to middle C. However, Yamaha give this note the *name* C3, while Roland use the conventional name C4 for middle C (MIDI note 60).

Comment: Sorry for my curiosity, but may I know in which class/topic did you get this assignment? Is this something related to an introduction of digital music/MIDI? And also, probably some short background on what have you learned from that class? Probably that might add some context to this assignment and question.

Answer (score 34):

Middle C, the C written below the treble clef and above the bass clef, has MIDI note 60. Conventionally, this note is referred to as C4. However, Yamaha refers to MIDI note 60 (middle C) as C3. Another major music equipment company, Roland, refers to this note as C4, as is conventional.

Therefore, the first note in your first diagram is B4 in “Roland pitch” and B3 in “Yamaha pitch”.

To find the “Roland pitch” of a given note, use your second diagram; the “Yamaha pitch” of a note is the same with the number being one lower.

BTW, I found out about this while using Apple’s Logic Pro X. By default this uses the name C3 for MIDI note 60 (middle C). This totally confused me and prompted me to Google an explanation. As it happens, Logic allows you to choose either “Roland C4” or “Yamaha C3” for MIDI note 60, hence why I knew what you were asking about...!

Comment: BTW, I’m answering on a mobile, so it’s a bit hard for me to link to online sources backing up this information. I’ll do this when I get home.

Comment: If this is all the teacher wanted, I have to say -- what a banal, boring, tedious assignment!

Comment: Couldn’t agree more, Carl... pretty pointless...

Comment: I love that Logic's default is, ironically, illogical.

Comment: Perhaps a better, more searching question should be 'Why has Yamaha gone against the rest (or most of the rest) of the music world?' +1.